# Can't select supported max. resolution with HDMI Ubuntu 13.10 AMD card

Tags: ati, resolution, hdmi

I've got an AMD graphics card (6900 series) and just installed the beta driver (after fighting with the stable one). I'm also using a screen with 2560x1440 resolution connected via HDMI which works fine on Windows (so I assume there is nothing wrong with the screen itself) but not on Ubuntu. The maximum resolution I can select is 1920x1080 which looks ugly.

However, I can use 2560x1440 with DVI but I use the built in speakers via HDMI so I'd like to keep that.

I've tried to use xrandr to basically fake it but xrandr can't find a HDMI output I could add the new mode to.

My OS is freshly installed except for the driver.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case somebody finds this via Google:

The 6900 series does not allow for HDMI in a resolution above 1080p. It worked on my Windows machine because the drivers I used there were old and buggy. The drivers I used on Linux were not so it didn't allow me to go above 1080p (as it was supposed to).